# Using “runas /user” to run a batch file and seemingly nothing happens

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, runas

If I run this command, after entering my password, all I see is a shortly blinking new `cmd` window, then nothing.

```
runas /user:<username> batch_file.bat
```

My batch file contains a `pause` command which should therefore require me to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and so I would at least expect the `cmd` window to persist until that point in my batch file.

Am I doing anything wrong? How can this be fixed?

Comment: The `runas` is supposed to ask for the password before running the batch file. Does this username have a password? Does it work from an elevated CMD?

Comment: It asks for a password, that seems fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `runas /user:<user> "cmd /k batch_file.bat"` and the error should become obvious:
`batch_file.bat` isn't even found, because the new process is run in the folder `C:\WINDOWS\system32`, but your script surely is stored somewhere else. Give it an absolute path:

```
runas /user:<user> "cmd /k "F:\ull path\to\batch_file.bat""
```

or in your short version:

```
runas /user:<user> "F:\ull path\to\batch_file.bat"
```

Comment: I actually came up with something similar on my own : `runas /user:<user> ".\batch_file.bat & pause"` but to the same effect of leaving the window open after runnign and indeed saw that `runas` runs out of `C:\WINDOWS\system32` as you said. Thanks though !

Comment: `".\batch_file.bat"` is still a *relative*  path (relative to the current working folder), which in this case results in an absolute path of `C:\Windows\system32\batch_file.bat`

Comment: Yep that was the issue, which I discovered with the method mentionned in my other comment.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `runas` is returning some error, which you don't see, instead of running the `.bat` file.

You can at least see the error if you issue the command from a `cmd` window. Then you can react to the provided error.

To see the error you need to issue the `runas ...` command from a `cmd` window - to know what is the error, fix it and later you will be able to run the batch file correctly. You should receive `pause` prompt for a keystroke.

Surely if you don't get `pause` message and computer does not wait for keystroke - that means it does not run the batch file.

Comment: Issue WHICH command from a `cmd` window ?

Comment: The command in the batch file. Or, you could add a pause at the end of the batch file to see if it's getting called at all.

Comment: I don't understand. There isn't a single command in my batch file, to be sure. And, if the one `pause` in the middle doesn't get executed (or not the way I think it should), why would one at the end ?

Comment: No, you need to issue `runas` command with all options in `cmd` window to see what error appears. If `pause` in batch file is not working - it is telling that the batch file is not started.

Comment: No but to be clear : issuing the `runas` command with all my options from the `cmd` _is already what I'm doing_, with the symptoms described. However you were right that there was an error involved.

Answer (score 0):

If a batch script contains the pause command, but executing the script flashes but then not pauses is caused if there is a syntax error in the script.

For example, your script uses `if exists filename echo test`,
but in reality it is `if exist filename echo test` the script will give a syntax error and not execute properly.

To troubleshoot your script, open a command prompt, navigate to the script, and type in the command you want to test, for example: `mybatch.cmd`.

This will display the error in the script and return to the existing command prompt,  keeping the error on screen.

The Runas will always launch it in a new window but as long as there's no syntax error in the script, which was tested in the previous step, the pause will work there. In that case you can now try and use: `runas /user:myuser mybatch.cmd`.

Comment: Hm, I mean the script in the batch file works when running from a command line - what I mean is, it achieves its functional purpose. That some of the commands along the script return error, is totally possible - but also not at all a functional problem. The script just tries a few different things in a sequence, some of which will work, which is good enough for me.

Comment: I removed what I thought might be the error-returning commands. No change.